# How Heroku Post hook processors work, and how to learn more about building such animals

Tags: ruby, heroku, github, git-post-receive

I recently deployed a ruby app that leverages some native heroku features to run a post-commit hook via github.

https://github.com/ajlai/github-heroku-pusher.

Now I am curious on how it works and how I might go about building a similar, low level plugin to heroku, possibly in another langauge.

**A brief summary of What the program does:**

Basically, this ruby program :

- Automatically deploys my heroku every time I push to github
- Is configured by only 4 parameters (the main one being the heroku API key).
- Works perfectly right out of the box : required no specific mucking with heroku. I simply deployed this application as a new heroku app, and added the post recieve hooks to github, and then found that heroku was automatically building my application for me everytime I commited it to github.

**My questions on how this ruby script (https://github.com/ajlai/github-heroku-pusher/blob/master/web.rb) is working to drive this github to heroku auto deploy service**

- It appears to run a shell command.  Is that even allowed in heroku ?
- Where is does the actual "git pull" from github occuring ? I see a "GitPusher" object, but its not clear where that object is defined (I suspect that is it a ruby gem object that is statically imported into the class, but I don't see what gem it might come from).
- I'm wondering where the brave soul who built this project found the documentation necessary for building such a low-level hook for Heroku.  Any hints as to how I could go about building custom worker hooks (preferably in a language other than Ruby) of the same ilk would be appreciated.

Comment: The source is [right there](https://github.com/ajlai/github-heroku-pusher/blob/master/lib/git.rb) and not terribly big or complicated.

Comment: It'd just be re-pushing to heroku (the remote named heroku) I'd say... that's how you do it locally, from memory. That's different from shelling into heroku and pulling.

Comment: @jayunit100, dude, the source code (in lib) is like 70 lines long in total, over 3 files. Just read it ;)

Comment: apologies for making this question seem deceptively trivial :)....  my question is not on "what the code is doing" ... but "how it is working". In particular - (1) Regarding the GitPusher object - how it works and where it comes from and (2) How the heroku documentation and security settings would be used to let this source code work.

Comment: correction ! your right - I never looked in lib/, which is where the RubyGem git.rb file is located !  I assumed it was simply binaries.... forgot about how libs in ruby are actual scripts :) -- In any case, my question remains regarding how one might construct such an application from scratch, given only heroku documentation on privileges and locally available APIs.

Comment: in https://github.com/ajlai/github-heroku-pusher/blob/master/lib/git.rb , when you see `\`rm -r #{local_folder}\`` that's actully executing that bash command. And yes, it seems heroku lets you run them. Try `heroku run bash`